# Three.js Animate Text error geometry.faces

Tags: javascript, text, three.js

In [this three.js Text example](https://codepen.io/zadvorsky/pen/xVrMMO) they animate text, i am trying to implement it on React/Three.js but i got the error TypeError: can't access property "length", geometry.faces is undefined
in BAS.Utils.separateFaces(geometry) line. Could someone help me please? Heres my code.-

```
createTextAnimation() {
  var geometry = this.generateTextGeometry('Welcome', {
    size:14,
    height:0,
    font:'droid sans',
    weight:'bold',
    style:'normal',
    bevelSize:0.75,
    bevelThickness:0.50,
    bevelEnabled:true,
    anchor:{x:0.5, y:0.0, z:0.5}
  });

  BAS.Utils.separateFaces(geometry); --------->>>Heres error

  return new TextAnimation(geometry);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to contain a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example of the problem. If you only link us to working code, we are unable to tell you where you erred in trying to implement that code.

Comment: Thank you @DMGregory i have updated my post, but its basically the same as of the example provided